# test whether button being clicked before running function on element.blur()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function called showHide() that alternately shows and hides a text input field and a button (button2) when another button (button1) is clicked. The text input field is automatically focused when it opens, and this works great.

The HTML looks roughly thus:

```
<button1>Show/Hide</button>
<form>
  <input class="hidden" type="text" />
  <button2 type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("button1.someSelectors").click(function() {showHide();});
  $("input.someSelectors").blur(function() {showHide();})
</script>
```

I would like to extend the function such that when the input field loses focus it and button1 disappear, *unless* it loses focus because button1 is being clicked. As it reads now I'm only testing whether the input field has focus or not. How can I also check whether button2 is being clicked or not?

I tried:

```
$("input.someSelectors").blur(function() {
  if (!$("button2.someSelectors").is(":focus")) {
    showHide();
  }
});
```

but it hid the form elements even when I tried clicking button2.

An alternative would be to test whether button2 is being clicked or not in the "hide" part of the function, but when I added

```
if(!$("button2.someSelectors").click()) {do the hide part of the function}
```

to showHide(), the form got submitted when I clicked button1 *or* button2. Here is an [example](http://claymanmatthews.com/registry/example.php) of my problem. Can anyone help?

--*Edit:*

```
var showHide=function(item, category) {
  if($("input."+item+"."+category).hasClass("hidden")) {
    $("input."+item+"."+category).show("fast").focus().removeClass("hidden");
    $("button.buy."+item+"."+category).show("fast");
    $("button.purchase."+item+"."+category).text("Never mind!");
  } else {
    $("input."+item).hide("fast").addClass("hidden");
    $("button.buy."+item).hide("fast");
    $("button.purchase."+item).text("Purchase");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`blur` event on `textbox` is triggered before the `click` event fires on the button. In order to avoid that you can use `mousedown` event instead of `click` event which will be triggered before `click` event. Try this

```
 $("button1.someSelectors").mousedown(function() {showHide();});
 $("input.someSelectors").blur(function() {showHide();})
```

Comment: mousedown != click -> Meaning Click != (mousedown on button and mouseout of the button and mouseup)

Comment: This causes the form fields to appear and immediately disappear. Might it be that input.blur() is being tested before input.focus() is being applied by the showHide() function?

Comment: In the event that it helps, I've uploaded a fully (dys)functional [example](http://claymanmatthews.com/registry/example.php) with all the relevant markup and scripting. The `showHide()` script has also been added to the original post.

Comment: +1 because I completely forgot that mousedown can fire WELL before the click even depending on the user.  Thanks for the reminder!